# xslt to transform format of xml document

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

i have the xml in a structure such as this:

```
<RWFCriteria reportType="ProgramReview">
  <item id="36" name="" value="9" type="Milestone" />
  <item id="31" name="" value="9" type="Milestone" />
  <item id="33" name="" value="11" type="Milestone" />
</RWFCriteria>
```

and need to it be converted to:

```
<data>
  <release id="9">  <milestone id="36" /> <milestone id="31" /> </release>
  <release id="11"> <milestone id="33" /> </release>
</data>
```

what would the XSLT look like for this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the items based on their value attribute. If you are using xslt 1 you can do this using the Muenchian Method which would look something like:

```
  <xsl:key name="item-value" match="item" use="@value" />

  <xsl:template match="/RWFCriteria">

    <data>
      <xsl:for-each select="item[count(. | key('item-value', @value)[1]) = 1]">
        <release id="{@value}">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('item-value', @value)">
            <milestone id="{@id}" />
          </xsl:for-each>
        </release>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </data>

  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for fixing the attributes

Comment: No problem. +1 For a correct answer. (Besides I don't like nested `xsl:for-each`)

Comment: @Alejandro Me neither, I would normally palm things off to their own template but I felt it was clearer.